# Failed to convert Object Detection model to tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am using tf2.0 and object detection API. I have a pretrained ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco model and I want to convert it to tensorflow lite(and do float16 quantization).

In the folder of the model, I have checkpoint, frozen_inference_graph.pb, model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001, model.ckpt.index, model.ckpt.meta, pipeline.config, and saved_model folder.

I used the following command to get the tflite.pb
python3 export_tflite_ssd_graph.py --output_directory=/home/tflite --pipeline_config_path=/home/exportedLP1/pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix=/home/exportedLP1/model.ckpt

Then I used the following python code to convert tflite.pb:

```py
frozen_model_path = '/home/tflite/tflite_graph.pb'  
input_arrays=["image_tensor"]  
output_arrays=["detection_boxes","detection_scores","num_detections","detection_classes"]  
input_tensor={"image_tensor":[1,300,300,3]}
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(frozen_model_path, input_arrays, output_arrays, input_tensor)  
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

The last step tflite = converter.convert() caused "abort(core dumped)'. According to posts I read online, I should be able to convertt to tflite without any issue.

Current thread 0x00007efbff6f1740 (most recent call first):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/toco/python/toco_from_protos.py", line 56 in execute
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250 in _run_main
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299 in run
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40 in run
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/toco/python/toco_from_protos.py", line 93 in main
File "/usr/local/bin/toco_from_protos", line 8 in
Aborted (core dumped)
```